# Errors in finding column mean of .csv file with NA cells in R

Tags: r, csv, na

I have a folder with several .csv files containing raw data with multiple rows and 39 columns (x obs. of 39 variables), which have been read into R as follows:

```
# Name path containing .csv files as folder 
folder = ("/users/.../");

# Find the number of files in the folder
file_list = list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")

# Read files in the folder
for (i in 1:length(file_list))
  {
  assign(file_list[i], 
         read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep='')))
}
```

I want to find the mean of a specific column in each of these .csv files and save it in a vector as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list))
{
  clean = na.omit(file_list[i])
  ColumnNameMean[i] = mean(clean["ColumnName"])
}
```

When I run the above fragment of code, I get the error "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA". This happens in spite of attempting to remove the NA values using na.omit. Using complete.cases,

```
clean = file_list[i][complete.cases(file_list[i]), ]
```

I get the error: incorrect number of dimensions, even though the number of columns haven't been explicitly stated.

How do I fix this?

Edit: corrected clean[i] to clean (and vice versa). Ran code, same error.

[Sample .csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2wR9Sp9S2hiOG9vZkZKdFpTNmtVTHFudXcyRkNtMXk2Rm5n/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why `clean[i]` instead of `clean` in `ColumnNameMean[i] = mean(clean[i]["ColumnName"])` ? Change it and let me know if it fixes thing.

Comment: Try double brackets for `file_list[[i]]`. Using single brackets after a list returns a list, not a dataframe

Comment: @Jrakru56, it doesn't help. Tried changing both ways, i.e. both clean[i] in the for loop, and both clean in the for loop.

Comment: In addition, you will likely have to change the column extraction to `clean[,"ColumnName"]`

Comment: @astrofunkswag: got this error Error in clean[, "ColumnName"] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: can you post one of the dataset that you use?

Comment: @Jrakru56: Done. So,

Comment: Thanks! I see what is going on. `assign(file_list[i], read.csv(file_list[i]))` is the guilty party. `file_list[i]` get resolve first and then assignment occurs.

Comment: ...It is EEG raw data. So the code would actually read as 'Delta_TP9Mean[i] = mean(clean["Delta_TP9"])'

Comment: @Jrakru56, could you please spell it out for me? I am afraid I don't really understand. What happens if assignment occurs after file_list[i] gets resolved first? Wouldn't doing it the other way 'round be syntactically incorrect? How do I correct for this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.

- `folder = ("/users/.../");` You don't need the parenthesis and you definitely do not need the semi-colon. **The semi-colon separates instructions, does not end them. So, this instruction is in fact two instructions, the  assigment of a string to `folder` and between the `;` and the newline the `NULL` instruction.**
- You are creating many objects in the global environment in the `for` loop where you `assign` the return value of `read.csv`. It is much better to read in the files into a list of data.frames.
- `na.omit` can remove all rows from the data.frames. And there is no need to use it since `mean` has a `na.rm` argument.
- You compute the mean values of each column of each data.frame. Though the data.frames are processed in a loop, the columns are not and R has a fast `colMeans` function.
- You mistake `[` for `[[`. The correct ways would be either `clean[, "ColumnName"]` or `clean[["ColumnName"]]`.

Now the code, revised. I present several alternatives to compute the columns' means.

First, read all files in one go. I set the working directory before reading them and reset after.

```
folder <- "/users/.../"
file_list <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = "^muse.*\\.csv$")
old_dir <- setwd(folder)
df_list <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)
setwd(old_dir)
```

Now compute the means of three columns.

```
cols <- c("Delta_TP9", "Delta_AF7", "Theta_TP9")
All_Means <- lapply(df_list, function(DF) colMeans(DF[cols], na.rm = TRUE))
names(All_Means) <- file_list
```

Compute the means of all columns starting with `Delta` or `Theta`. Get those columns names with `grep`.

```
df_names <- names(df_list[[1]])
cols2 <- grep("^Delta", df_names, value = TRUE)
cols2 <- c(cols2, grep("^Theta", df_names, value = TRUE))

All_Means_2 <- lapply(df_list, function(DF) colMeans(DF[cols2], na.rm = TRUE))
names(All_Means_2) <- file_list
```

Finally, compute the means of all numeric columns. Note that this time the index vector `cols3` is a logical vector.

```
cols3 <- sapply(df_list[[1]], is.numeric)
All_Means_3 <- lapply(df_list, function(DF) colMeans(DF[cols3], na.rm = TRUE))
names(All_Means_3) <- file_list
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest some good resources for R for a relative beginner? I am teaching myself, and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```r
setwd("U:/Playground/StackO/")


# Find the number of files in the folder
file_list = list.files(path=getwd(), pattern="*.csv")

# Read files in the folder
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i], 
         read.csv(file_list[i]))
}

ColumnNameMean <-  rep(NULL, length(file_list))

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  clean = get(file_list[i])
  ColumnNameMean[i] = mean(clean[,"Delta_TP10"])
}

ColumnNameMean
#> [1] 1.286201
```

I used `get` to retrieve the `data.frame` otherwise `file_list[i]` just returns a string. I think this is an idiom used in other languages like `python`. I tried to stay true to the way you were using but there are easier way than indexing like this.

Maybe this:

`lapply(list.files(path=getwd(), pattern="*.csv"), function(f){ dt <- read.csv(f); mean(dt[,"Delt`a_TP10"]) })

PS: Be careful with `na.omit()`, it removes ALL the rows with `NA` which in your case is your whole `data.frame` since `Elements` is only `NA`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I seem to be getting NA as the mean throughout ColumnNameMean, i.e. num[1:102] NA NA NA..., with the exception of one numerical mean at i = 99 in the list. I tried this for both the methods you described, the result is the same.

Comment: Do you want to apply the mean to all columns? Otherwise, you don't have a column `ColumnName`

Comment: I want to find the means of columns for all the files read. Whether the calculation is done for all columns together or each independently doesn't particularly matter at this point, as long as I can see (and retrieve) the data from the calculated mean. If you can point me to the correct resources to read up on R, I'd be quite grateful, especially a tutorial/guide that can help me understand the help file.

Comment: try this `lapply(list.files(path=getwd(), pattern="*.csv"), function(f){ dt <- read.csv(f); lapply(dt[,sapply(dt, class) == "numeric"], mean)} )`